# Create multiple RDDs from single file based on row value ( header record in sample file) using Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to create multiple RDDs to process independently from below file based on the similar format of data .

Please find the file with different data formats

```
custid,starttime,rpdid,catry,auapp,sppp,retatype,status,process,fileavil
4fgdfg,00:56:30.034,BM_-unit1,GEN,TRUE,FALSE,NONE,A,45,TRUE
X95GEK,00:56:32.083,CBM_OMDD_RSVCM0CBM-unit0,GEN,TRUE,FALSE,NONE,A,GWC,TRUE
XWZ08K,00:57:01.947,GWC-0-UNIT-1,GEN,TRUE,FALSE,NONE,A,GWC,TRUE
custid,relstatus
fg3-03,R
dfsdf4-01,V
56fbfg,R
devid,reg,hold,devbrn,lname,lcon
CTUTANCM0CBM,TRUE,FALSE,13:17:36.934,CBM_BMI_25_5_2,13:43:21.370
```

In the above file, we have three different type of data formats exist and I want to split the file into three different RDDs as per the format.

Could you please suggest how to implement using Spark (Scala)?

Comment: All of the 3 different types of data that you showed are available in a single file?

Comment: Yes. all are available in a single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file looks like it has 3 different csv files in it.

You can read it as a single file and extract 3 RDDs from it based on the number of fields you have in each row.

```
// Caching because you'll be filtering it thrice
val topRdd = sc.textFile("file").cache
topRdd.count
//res0: Long = 10

val rdd1 = topRdd.filter(_.split(",", -1).length == 10 )
val rdd2 = topRdd.filter(_.split(",", -1).length ==  2 )
val rdd3 = topRdd.filter(_.split(",", -1).length ==  6 )

rdd1.collect.foreach(println)
// custid,starttime,rpdid,catry,auapp,sppp,retatype,status,process,fileavil
// 4fgdfg,00:56:30.034,BM_-unit1,GEN,TRUE,FALSE,NONE,A,45,TRUE
// X95GEK,00:56:32.083,CBM_OMDD_RSVCM0CBM-unit0,GEN,TRUE,FALSE,NONE,A,GWC,TRUE
// XWZ08K,00:57:01.947,GWC-0-UNIT-1,GEN,TRUE,FALSE,NONE,A,GWC,TRUE

rdd2.collect.foreach(println)
// custid,relstatus
// fg3-03,R
// dfsdf4-01,V
// 56fbfg,R

rdd3.collect.foreach(println)
// devid,reg,hold,devbrn,lname,lcon
// CTUTANCM0CBM,TRUE,FALSE,13:17:36.934,CBM_BMI_25_5_2,13:43:21.370
```

Comment: Thank you.   But two different RDDs are having same length then it may not give as a two different RDDs right?  Can you please suggest about that.

Comment: Yes it won't. I'm not sure about the latter.

Comment: Actually I want to combine all these three rdds  as a single rdd even there is no relation between them.  Can we do that?

Comment: I don't understand. `sc.textFile` will give you the whole file as one RDD

Comment: Yes, But I want to filter the data from each rdd and combine all the filtered RDDs

Comment: Why filter if you will combine them again ?

Comment: Actually I don't want all the column from each rdd. Let's take from first rdd I want coulmn one,three,five and from second rdd colum two and from third rdd column two,four. I need to create one RDD with all the above columns even though no relation between them. Can we do that?

Comment: Sure, you can. `split` on `,`. Use `map` on each rdd to get the columns you want, you'll get 3 new rdds with the required columns in it. Use `union` to join all 3 rdds. I suggest going through the Spark documentation. These are very basic operations and can be performed in no time if you go through the documentation and examples thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you. As part of the above file i am having a  below two lines also.

>prsm;select informsite
Already in a value increment, Type value for a list of commands.

When we are splitting the file based on the column length, the above two lines are storing as part of  2nd rdd which is having  column length as two. But these two lines are not belongs to that file. It seems the logic is taking all the records which was having column length as two. But it should take it. Could you please help to provide the solution on this.

Comment: These are the two lines : 

 line one: >prsm;select informsite


 line two :Already in a value increment, Type value for a list of commands.